# Fastest way to search a string in a file

Tags: c, string, tree, time-complexity, hashtable

I need to do a "find function" for a project. I have to search all the same  strings (of course only one written by the operator) and how many they are in a huge file in the fastest way possible. 
I thought about a tree connected with a hash table but I don't know if It's correct.

1. How can I do it with strings (I usually use numbers)?
2. What should be the best data structure to use (complexity)?

Comment: This depends on a lot of things that aren't clear in the question. For example, what is the content of the files?

Comment: Do you have to find the **most common** strings in the file? **All the strings that occur *x* times**? How many times a **particular string** occurs?

Comment: Do you have code now that does exactly what you want, but not necessarily optimally?  (That might be a good place to start.)

Comment: I have to find only that specific word (non pieces of it). It could appear thousand times. I just need to know about the data structure and his complexity.

Comment: @SteveSummit Nope. I wanna know how to think before doing it. Of course I can't just use a normal loop 'cause It's too much slow.

Comment: You probably want a DFA of the kind that `egrep` uses.  I would do some research about the algorithms underlying `egrep`.

Comment: If the search string is `"abca"`and the file is `"abcabca"`, is that 1 or 2 matches?

Comment: Suggest you first code a solution that _functional_ works and _then_ post it asking for performance improvements.

Comment: Does the null character occur in the file and/or search pattern?

Comment: Might the file exceed memory capacity such that is can not be read in all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming worst case:

- huge (1 Tebibyte) file
- highly varied and highly repetitive content. Let's take `/usr/share/dict/words` with its ~100,000 words (here), concatenate until we have one Tebibyte which gives about 1.1 mio. repetitions and mix it up.
- a non-repetitive (or close to non-repetitive) short (say 1-20 bytes, 10 on average) input.

The choice of algorithm depends on

- number of inputs (inputs/second)
- available memory

If you have only a handful (numbers intentionally kept vague) of inputs and/or not much memory available you can just search for it linearly (Boyer-Moor(-Horspool), Rabin-Karp, Apostolico-Giancarlo, Knuth-Morris-Pratt).

Ir you have a lot of inputs and some memory available you can index the file first (O(n), obviously) and search either in O(1) with a hashtable or O(log n) with a binary search tree (there are several optimizations possible but let's keep it simple).

Not much memory is needed. No matter what you do, a hashtable or a tree, you need to keep the position somewhere and because you have more than four Gibibytes you need a 64-bit counter. Eight bytes multiplied with the table size of 1.1 mio: just 8 Mebibytes. Plus space for the words themselves (less than one Mebibyte with my `/usr/share/dict/words`) or indices for the hashtable (a bit less because you don't need large integers for them with such a short wordlist).

You have some overhead for holding and managing the indices of the individual words in the big-file. A binary search tree is fast and quickly build, although it has quite some memory overhead. If you don't need to search the indices: just put them into a simple array.

tl;dr: index the file, that is make a hastable of the words and their places. Put the places (may need 64 bit integers!) in a simple array if you need them all at once but use a (binary) search tree if you need to search these indices. I assume here that you know how to build a perfect hash.